# MAGMI_RUN unable to find .CSV file

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, importexport, magmi

MAGMI has been successfully set up on my Magento environment (and Magento was set up via MS's web platform installer and is kicked off via MS's Webmatrix), and I can use it quite happily to import products, change stock and prices.  However, I'm now trying to automate this data import process.

I have enabled MAGMI Import URL plugin.

The folder structure on my webserver of the Magento set up is as follows:

[image]

The data .CSV files are being uploaded via FTP to `/data/upload`.

When I try to execute:

> *localhost:3502/magmi/web/magmi_run.php?mode=xcreate&profile=Orcus&engine=magmi_productimportengine:Magmi_ProductImportEngine&CSV:filename=/data/upload/muk_000000049_productupdate.csv -O /dev/null*

MAGMI fails because it cannot find the .CSV data file with:

> *...
>   Standard Attribute Import-1.1-Dweeves-
>   1:/data/upload/muk_000000049_productupdate.csv -O /dev/null not found -
>   Import Ended*

Why can't it find the file? What I am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and it was two problems.

The URL was (slightly) incorrect and the path to the CSV is relative to the location of magmi_productimportengine.php

So, the corrected URL is:

http://localhost:3502/magmi/web/magmi_run.php?mode=create&profile=Orcus&engine=magmi_productimportengine:Magmi_ProductImportEngine&CSV:filename=../../data/upload/muk_000000049_productupdate.csv

[image: Structure]

But, wow, it's much, much slower than using MAGMI's UI to import the file.